# Push уведомления для телефона при появлении акций на сайте

Tags: android, push-уведомления

Хочу сделать push уведомления для приложения при появлении акций на сайте через onesignal, на андроид и не знаю как.
Можете подсказать хотя бы как примерно это сделать? Приложение работает через web view.

Comment: Пуши делать примерно полчаса, если это в третий раз делать. Не очень понимаю, при чём тут onesignal и что он такое, засим посоветую посмотреть доку FCM - там описано как пуши принимать и отправлять.

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю как сделать зависящие от какого-то действия уведомления

Comment: Найти на бэке место в коде, которое отвечает за "появлении акций на сайте" и в это место вставить код рассылки пуша

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Здравствуйте, если вам не трудно можете отправить код для сайта и для самого приложения?  По его примеру мне быстро удастся понять как это сделать. Это мне сэкономит уйму времени которое я потрачу что бы разобратся в документах firebase

Comment: Очень долго собирать всю необходимую информацию, к сожалению у меня нет на это времени(